# How to avoid bind in react/redux container with components (ES6 classes)

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have simple react/redux app with container for search form with two destination autoselect components:

```
class QuoteBox extends Component {
    onSelectSuggest(target, destination) {
        this.props.setDestination(destination, target);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Destination
                    direction="From"
                    key="dest-from"
                    enterText={this.props.enterText.bind(this)}
                    onSelectSuggest={this.onSelectSuggest.bind(this, "origin")}
                    dataSource={this.props.originSuggests} />

            <Destination
                    direction="To"
                    key="dest-to"
                    enterText={this.props.enterText.bind(this)}
                    onSelectSuggest={this.onSelectSuggest.bind(this, "destination")}
                    dataSource={this.props.destinationSuggests} />
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        originSuggests: state.originSuggests,
        destinationSuggests: state.destinationSuggests,
        origin: state.origin,
        destination: state.destination
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({
        enterText: enterText,
        setDestination: setDestination
    }, dispatch)
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps )(QuoteBox)
```

and Destination is a simple component like

```
export default class Destination extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <AutoComplete
                    onUpdateInput = { _.debounce((term) => {
                        this.props.enterText(term);
                        this.setState({
                            searchText: term
                        })
                    }, 300) }
                    onNewRequest = {(x) =>{this.props.onSelectSuggest(x)}}
                    dataSource={this.props.dataSource} />
        )
    }
}
```

Which are just calling functions passed in via props on some events.

There was autobind feature but it is not available in ES6 classes: https://medium.com/@goatslacker/react-0-13-x-and-autobinding-b4906189425d#.nkv1cn32v 
I see many workarounds like 
http://www.ian-thomas.net/autobinding-react-and-es6-classes/
or 3rd party libraries.

What is modern way to avoid this bind(this) while passing methods from container to simple components?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a bunch of modern ways, but they all revolve around the same ideas :)

You could use an arrow function:

```
<Destination
  onSelectSuggest={destination => (
    this.props.setDestination(destination, 'origin')
  )}
/>
```

(I like this one because we get to ditch the argument-flipping `onSelectSuggest` method!)

For your simpler binds, you could use the ESNext bind operator (`::`):

```
<Destination
  enterText={::this.enterText}
/>
```

(Obviously, babel is needed for that one)

---

**EDIT September 27th 2017**: The 'bind' operator doesn't seem to be making it into the spec; the more modern approach is to use property initializer syntax (also an upcoming JS feature, but I believe it's much more likely to make it into the language):

```
class SomeComponent extends Component {
  enterText = () => {
    // body here
  }

  render() {
    return <Destination enterText={this.enterText} />
  }
}
```

---

Finally, the most efficient way is to do the binding in your constructor.

```
class QuoteBox extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.enterText = this.props.enterText.bind(this);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Destination
        enterText={this.enterText}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

The reason this is more efficient is because binding is pretty slow, and in your example it's being done on every render. Better to do it once, when it's initialized.

That said, **it probably doesn't matter either way**. Don't worry too much about performance until it becomes an issue; React is fast and unless you're dealing with a very complicated component tree, it's likely a negligible difference.

Similarly, in your AutoComplete, you should bind the debounced function in the constructor:

```
class Destination extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.updateInput = _.debounce(this.updateInput, 300)

  updateInput(term) {
    this.props.enterText(term); 
    this.setState({
      searchText: term
    }) 
  }  

  render() {
    return (
      <AutoComplete
        onUpdateInput={this.updateInput}
        onNewRequest={this.props.onSelectSuggest}
      />
    )
  }
}
```